# How to display last n inserted records using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi in the below image please observe the last two rows data based on the `transaction_id` I want to display last 2 record (the number may vary based on the data inserted before)  and want to update the data .

Please suggest me any other idea.  I am generating `transaction_id` as auto generated so it is changing during auto refresh.

```
id course_id donate_amount  transaction_id
1     1        1300           abcd
2     2        1300           abcd
3     1        1200           xyz
4     2        1200           xyz
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: can you explain me what u got and what u have not

Comment: I am working on a charity website  the donor can donate amount for multiple courses. Before redirecting it to payment gateway i am storing this data in my database. and after sucess transaction My intension is to update last  "N"  records suppose  observe transacion_id  (xyz) it is of 2 records na i want to make that status as active

Comment: How about this idea First i will display last generated id and then i will display transaction id and using that transaction id i will display the records..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this idea First i will display last generated id and then i will display transaction id and using that transaction id i will display the records..

Answer (score 0):

To get last inserted, updated or deleted rows, you can use `ROW_COUNT()` mysql function. After that you can execute
`"SELECT xxx FROM yyyORDER BY id desc LIMIT zzz"`, where zzz is the value get before from `ROW_COUNT()` function.

Comment: to get last inserted id won't work in my case....observe the transaction_id   xyz 2 times what if it is of 4 records then how can i display

Comment: How about this idea First i will display last generated id and then i will display transaction id   and using that transaction id i will display the records..............